# Cannot resolve 'get' method in 'HttpRequest'?

Tags: dart

Keep getting the error :

> Cannot resolve 'get' method in 'HttpRequest' since updated the latest build of Dart Editor 0.3.4_r18115.

What is the workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah... I don't know either, your code looks fine /sarcasmoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to face [this breaking change](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/4c3qhRE9Kro/discussion) :

> We'll be removing the HttpRequest.get and getWithCredentials factory constructors and replacing them with static methods returning futures. These are primarily ease-of-use methods and we're looking to make them a bit easier to use.

So you should now use something like :

```dart
HttpRequest.request(url).then((xhr) {
    var result = xhr.response;
  },
  onError: (e) {
     // error!
  });
```

instead of :

```dart
new HttpRequest.get(url, (xhr) {
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    var result = xhr.response;
  } else {
    // error?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Alexandre's answer is correct, although the  specific `new HttpRequest.get(...)` convenience constructor is replaced by an alternative convenience static method called `getString()`

```dart
HttpRequest.getString(url).then((responseText) {
  print(responseText);
});
```

Comment: This is throwing asynch error. when i tried HttpRequest.getString('http://www.google.com/')
           .then((response)=>print('response'))
           .catchError((error)=>print(error.toString()));